# Angular 2: Component/Service logic best practice?

Tags: angular, service, components

Suppose I have a list of user profiles. We define a user profile in a model class. A profile list component uses an *ngFor to iterate through the collection, and display each profile in a user profile component selector. Suppose there are form elements to edit these user profiles.

Who should be responsible for "maintaining" the list of user profiles? Does the list component make changes to the profile properties, and then call the service to make the HTTP call? Should the child component be doing that if it has a reference via a property binding to the user profile object? Or should the components *only* be doing UI logic, and instead relying on the service to handle save requests and updating the model, then publishing the updated list via an observable/subject?

Comment: The Component must only provide needed values to view (your html page). To retrieve data, save, update, delete ... it's better to create a service to handle all these actions and send back values, success or errors to component.

Comment: What about manipulating data? Should that be within a service or the component itself?